# dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key

Tags: macos, android-emulator

After trying to run the Emulator form Android Studio, i got the following:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key
Referenced from: /goinfre/anel-bou/FlutterFolder/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1)
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet 
in /goinfre/anel-bou/FlutterFolder/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.
```

And after trying to run Android Emulator without using Android Studio i got the following message:

```
e2r7p15% /goinfre/anel-bou/FlutterFolder/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5WebEngineWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /goinfre/anel-bou/FlutterFolder/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwinx86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort
```

I am working with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (that i cant update) and Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading the Emulator:

- 1. Download an old version of emulator (in my case i used **emulator-darwin_x64-7425822** [download from here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7425822.zip))
- 2. Replace the **emulator** folder you downloaded with the one in your sdk folder. (should normally be here `~/Library/Android/sdk`)

You can also fix it by upgrading your macOS version to the latest one.

Comment: Thanks! your download link seems dead, for me https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/AndroidSDK works albeit it seems horribly slow.

Comment: now the link is working, the emulator works slow because you are using an incompatible version of it, try changing the version or use the one i posted, Thanks