# Logcat not showing for Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android. I'm using Android Studio Hedgehog  2023.1.1 Patch 2 and MacBook Air & MacOS catalina. Virtual device not showing in logcat.

I tried to invalidate the cache and restart.

Deleted old virtual devices and created new. But no luck. Please see the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

> admin@Admins-MacBook-Air Lynk % /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_34 -netdelay none -netspeed full
> INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
> INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
> dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_enable_isolation_key
> Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1)
> Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet
> in /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
> zsh: abort      /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_34  none

Comment: 1) Does the emulator launch? 2)What does `adb devices` say?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Emulator not launching. Getting error `The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_34 has terminated.`

Comment: All emulators with other API level also cannot be launched?

Comment: @MorrisonChang , Yes. other API level also cannot be launched. Physical devices working fine.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I was recently updated android studio. After that its not working.

Comment: What output do you get if [you launch the emulator from command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) and just in case: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Added error message in my question.

Comment: There is an older question with the same error message: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70033392/150978 Not sure if Google really tests Android Studio fully on those old MacOS systems. Or may be Android Studio works but quemu not (the quemu project only supports the latest two MacOS versions).