Android Studio emulator issue macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
I had Android Studio on a Mac running Catalina version 10.15.7.
I created same emulators and worked ok.
I don't know which version of Android Studio was installed at that moment.
Then I was prompted to update Android Studio and I did it.
Since then my emulators emulators stop working if I try to start one from the terminal I get is the error:
$ emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_30_play
    INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
    INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/myUsername/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/
    dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_enable_isolation_key
    Referenced from: /Users/myUsername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1)
    Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet
    in /Users/myUsername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
    zsh: abort      /Users/myUsername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_30_play

I decided to completely uninstall Android Studio:
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Google/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio* ;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*;
rm -Rf ~/.gradle;
rm -Rf ~/.android;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*;
rm -Rf ~/.emulator_console_auth_token;

And try installing previous versions until I found one that worked correctly and installed:
Android Studio Jellyfish, Android Studio Hedgehog, ...  

But I get the same error than previously
  Referenced from: /Users/myUsername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1)

What I can't understand is that at first everything worked correctly and now I always get the same error.
Someone has find the same problems?
Could someone help me with this?

No matter which Android Studio version you install the Android SDK which also includes the emulator is directly downloaded from Google servers. And this is by default the latest version and this version is not compatible with your OS version. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/70033392/150978

Even if you choose custom installation in Anfroid Studio the checkboxes cannot modify their value so custom installation will always be same that default)
